# Can not link a Series to a chart SeriesDefinitions in BIRT

Tags: java, api, charts, birt, radar-chart

I am trying hard to implement a charting extension to an app that i am developing : so my problem is that I have written some code (the boiler plate one) for doing this in BIRT.

At some place in the code, I have to link the dataset to a series and link the series to a seriesdefinition object which finally will be attached to the charts seriesDefinitions like this

```
  RadarSeries radarSeries = RadarSeriesImpl.create();
  radarSeries.setDataSet(numberDataValues);
  radarSeries.setSeriesIdentifier("Number data values");
  radarSeries.getLabel().setVisible(true);
```

where numberDataValues is an array of doubles. Then I create my seriesDefinition :

```
  SeriesDefinition seriesDefinition = SeriesDefinitionImpl.create();
  seriesDefinition.getSeriesPalette().shift(0);
```

But then, here comes the time when I have to LINK my radarSeries to the seriesDefinition like this :

```
  seriesDefinition.getSeriesDefinitions().add(radarSeries);
```

**THE PROBLEM** : I don't have the **getSeriesDefinitions()** method when trying to call it from code (doing a Ctrl+Space in Eclipse).

Needless to say that I can't call the **getSeriesDefinitions()** method on myChart object :

```
  myChart.getSeriesDefinitions().add(seriesDefinition);
```

**FOR YOUR INFORMATION** : I have included my birt jars manually in my local maven repository and the details of these dependencies are :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
            <artifactId>engineapi</artifactId>
            <version>${birtVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
            <artifactId>coreapi</artifactId>
            <version>${birtVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
            <artifactId>scriptapi</artifactId>
            <version>${birtVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
            <artifactId>chartengineapi</artifactId>
            <version>${birtVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
```

where ${birtVersion} = 2.6.2

here is a link to the official example of the 2.6.2 release of birt about RadarChart : [Radar chart official release example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse.birt.chart/examples/2.6.0/org/eclipse/birt/chart/examples/view/models/Radar.java#Radar.createRadar%28%29)

Can somebody help me ? I really can't believe I didn't found out how to do this in a 3days google search session : that not serious! ... given its popularity and its power, I think they should have invested more effort in the documentation ...

@Birt guyz (if any) > sorry to be so dramatic guys, but I really think that the doc side really sucks ... I hope to be able to help you on this (really, I do)

Here is the code :

```
public String drawChart() {
        // Birt Vars
    IDeviceRenderer iDeviceRenderer = null;
    IDisplayServer iDisplayServer = null;
    RunTimeContext context;
    Chart chart = null;

    // Birt Platform configuration
    PlatformConfig platformConfig = new PlatformConfig();
    platformConfig.setProperty("STANDALONE", true);

    // Creating Chart Engine
    ChartEngine chartEngine = ChartEngine.instance(platformConfig);
    IGenerator iGenerator = chartEngine.getGenerator();
    if(iGenerator == null)
        System.out.println("IGenerator NULL");
    else
        System.out.println("IGenerator NOT NULL");

    try {
        // iDeviceRenderer = chartEngine.getRenderer("dv.PNG");
        iDeviceRenderer = chartEngine.getRenderer("dv.GIF");
        iDisplayServer = iDeviceRenderer.getDisplayServer();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Creating Chart
    ChartWithoutAxes radarChart = ChartWithoutAxesImpl.create( );
    radarChart.setDimension( ChartDimension.TWO_DIMENSIONAL_LITERAL );
    radarChart.setType(Radar.TYPE_LITERAL); //$NON-NLS-1$   
    radarChart.setSubType( "Standard Radar Chart" ); //$NON-NLS-1$

    // Plot
    radarChart.setSeriesThickness( 10 );

    // Legend
    Legend lg = radarChart.getLegend( );
    lg.getOutline( ).setVisible( true );

    // Title
    radarChart.getTitle( )
            .getLabel( )
            .getCaption( )
            .setValue( "Radar Chart" );//$NON-NLS-1$

    try {

        if(radarChart != null)
            System.out.println("RADAR CHART NOT NULL");
        else
            System.out.println("RADAR CHART NULL!!!");

        // PREPARE PHASE
        context = Generator.instance().prepare(radarChart, null, null, ULocale.getDefault());
        if(context == null)
            System.out.println("CONTEXT NULL ");
        else
            System.out.println("CONTEXT NOT NULL");

        //BIND PHASE : fetch data from DB
        NumberDataSet numberDataValues = NumberDataSetImpl.create( new double[]{
                54, 21, 75, 91, 37
        } );

        // Radar series
        RadarSeries radarSeries = RadarSeriesImpl.create();
        radarSeries.setDataSet(numberDataValues);
        radarSeries.setSeriesIdentifier("Number data values");
        radarSeries.getLabel().setVisible(true);

        SeriesDefinitionImpl seriesDefinition = (SeriesDefinitionImpl) SeriesDefinitionImpl.create();
        seriesDefinition.getSeriesPalette().shift(0);

           // ERROR HERE : can't call the method
           seriesDefinition.getSeriesDefinitions()

        // RENDERING PHASE
        if(iDisplayServer == null)
            System.out.println("DISPLAY SERVER NULL");
        else
            System.out.println("DISPLAY SERVER NOT NULL");

        GeneratedChartState generatedChartState = iGenerator.build(iDisplayServer, radarChart, null, null, context);
        iGenerator.render(iDeviceRenderer, generatedChartState);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

**EDIT + SOLUTION**

Sorry for the delay : I should have posted this answer earlier to mark this question as solved.
Just use the RCP report designer to create your report document. Copy ReportEngine/lib/*jars to your /WEB-INF/lib; also create a platform/ directory under WEB-INF/ and copy BIRT ReportEngine configuration/ and plugins/ directories under the newly created WEB-INF/platform/ folder. Now with the *.rptdesign file that you have created in your BIRT RCP designer tool, you will have to use the BIRT API which will allow you to interact with your report...

Comment: According to the example you're referring to, your code is missing some parts. Can you turn the question into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: I have given the whole code ...

Comment: When you hover over seriesDefinition (or SeriesDefinition) what class is it showing?

Comment: Eureka!! guys, when including the jars for your project : take those from the ReportEngines/lib directory and those from the plugins directory that you need (e.g in our case : *chart* jars)

Comment: So I take it my suggestion (hover) helped you find the answer. Too bad I didn't put in an answer ;-) I suggest you add your answer to your post as an edit.

Comment: Never mind : just use the RCP report designer to create your report document. Copy ReportEngine/lib/*jars to your /WEB-INF/lib; also create a platform/ directory under WEB-INF/ and copy BIRT ReportEngine configuration/ and plugins/ directories under the newly created WEB-INF/platform/ folder.
Now with the *.rptdesign file that you have created in your BIRT RCP designer tool, you will have to use the BIRT API which will allow you to interact with your report...

Comment: @kaffein You really should post your answer and accept it so others will know there is answer without having to read through the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay : I should have posted this answer earlier to mark this question as solved.

Just use the RCP report designer to create your report document.
Then copy ReportEngine/lib/*jars to your /WEB-INF/lib; also create a platform/ directory under WEB-INF/ and copy BIRT ReportEngine configuration/ and plugins/ directories under the newly created WEB-INF/platform/ folder.

Now with the *.rptdesign file that you have created in your BIRT RCP designer tool, you will have to use the BIRT API which will allow you to interact with your report...